# Gnuplot: Plotting boundary box around a 3d surface

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting several 3D graphs with Gnuplot after experimenting a bit with Google's nice graphing tool. One thing I like from Google's tool is the "boundary box" that it draws around the surface, which makes it easier for me to see the size.

Is there any way to plot this boundary box in Gnuplot?

For instance, this function: `z = (15 - x*y) / (100 - x)`

Plotted with Google: [https://www.google.es/search?q=z+%3D+(15+-+x*y)%2F(100-x)&aq=f&oq=z+%3D+(15+-+x*y)%2F(100-x)](https://www.google.es/search?q=z%20=%20%2815%20-%20x*y%29/%28100-x%29&aq=f&oq=z%20=%20%2815%20-%20x*y%29/%28100-x%29)

[image: 3D surface plot with Google]

An equivalent script for Gnuplot:

```
    set grid
    set xrange [-10:10]
    set yrange [-10:10]
    set zrange [-0.7:1]
    set isosamples 100
    set pm3d
    set hidden3d
    set ticslevel 0.0
    set view 60, 100
    splot (15 - x*y) / (100 - x)
```

Yields the following plot:

[image: 3D surface plot with Gnuplot]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can turn on the boundary by using the command

```
set border 4095
```

(`help set border` for an explanation of that number: in short there is one bit per border edge and there are 12 edges on a cube.)

Gnuplot doesn't draw the tics on each of the border lines, though.